# I am try to run same query on some tables on mysql 8 by using a cursor. I can not understand what is the problem in my code

Tags: mysql, loops, cursor

I am trying to run a same query on some tables and retrieve data from them but after running the query it says 0 row affected and the result table is empty.
I am using a cursor.
I can not get what is the problem

```
delimiter //

drop procedure if exists hunt //
create procedure hunt()
begin
    DECLARE done int default false;
    DECLARE table_name CHAR(255);
    declare sqll longtext;

    DECLARE cur1 cursor for SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "xyz_database" and table_name LIKE "%vendor%" ;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    open cur1;

    myloop: loop
        fetch next from cur1 into table_name;
        if done then
            leave myloop;
        end if;

        set sqll ='INSERT INTO Task1_AverageCapacities SELECT AVG(capacity) as AverageCapacity
FROM (SELECT cycle,MAX(mAh_transferred_during_discharging) as capacity
FROM'+table_name+' where cycle<101
GROUP BY cycle) AS avg_capacity;';

        PREPARE stmt FROM @sqll;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt ;


    end loop;

    close cur1;
end //

delimiter ;

call hunt();
```

Comment: Are you sure that your INSERT syntax is correct?

Comment: @shn when I replace the table_name variable(I mean "+table_name+")  with one of the tables name and run it alone outside of the procedure it works

Comment: Ok, so you know that the second query works, can you check that the first query is actually outputting rows, because if it weren't the loop would run 0 times.

Comment: If you are doing this query on a database, your user may not have permissions to query the mysql database, which houses the table schema

Comment: @shn if by first query you mean SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "calce_battery_database" and table_name LIKE "%vendor%" ; I would say yes. It returns 8 rows which are name of my tables

Comment: @shn I created the database and imported all the tables so I think I should have access

Comment: Try running it with root user

Comment: @shn I run it with root user

Comment: Can you print to make sure the loop is running more than once.

Comment: @shn I put Select * from task1_averagecapacities; in the loop but nothing happened. Does it mean the loop does not run even once?

Comment: I'm not familiar with cursor but yes likely.

Comment: MySQL doesn't use `+` for string concatenation. You also need a space after `FROM` in `FROM'+table_name+'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `CONCAT()` function to do string concatenation, not the `+` operator.

And you need a space between `FROM` and the table name.

```
set sqll = CONCAT('INSERT INTO Task1_AverageCapacities SELECT AVG(capacity) as AverageCapacity
FROM (SELECT cycle,MAX(mAh_transferred_during_discharging) as capacity
FROM ', table_name, ' where cycle<101
GROUP BY cycle) AS avg_capacity;');
```

And the name of the variable is `sqll`, not `@sqll`, so you prepare it with:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM sqll;
```